# Renaming the Group of Files in C# (Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, winforms

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2010, Windows Forms Application.

Hi! I would like to rename (batch) some files... 
1.
I have (around 50 000 files): abc.mp3, def.mp3, ghi.mp3 
I want: abc1.mp3, def1.mp3, ghi1.mp3

2.
I have (around 50 000 files): abc.mp3, def.mp3, ghi.mp3
I want: 1abc.mp3, 1def.mp3, 1ghi.mp3

Something similar...

```
    FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    folderDlg.ShowDialog();

    string[] mp3Files = Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath, "*.mp3");
    string[] newFileName = new string[mp3Files.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < mp3Files.Length; i++)
    {
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(mp3Files[i]);
        string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(mp3Files[i]);

        newFileName = mp3Files[i];

        File.Move(mp3Files[i], filePath + "\\" + newFileName[1] + 1 + fileExt);
    }
```

But this code doesn't work. Error here... `newFileName = mp3Files[i];`
And I cannot to convert it correctly.
Thank You!

Comment: `newFileName` is an array of string, while `mp3Files[i]` is a single string. You cannot assign a single string to an array of strings.

Comment: @MetroSmurf, I believe that is the problem with the code, your comment should be an answer

Comment: Yes! I know it. So how can I resolve it? I always have problems with conversions.

Comment: @user922907, just define string `newFileName` as: `string newFileName = string.Empty;` in your code. It doesn't have to be a string array

Comment: @Habib - It is late here and I'm heading to bed... I'll leave it to the community to post a complete answer; not only to the conversion issue but to the other potential issues as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest option would be use direct OS renaming function. Use process object to run shell CMD with /C switch. Use the "ren" command line renaming.

```
Process cmd = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = @"/C  REN c:\full\path\*.mp3 c:\full\path\1*.mp3"
    }
};

cmd.Start();
cmd.WaitForExit();

//Second example below is for renaming with file.mp3 to file1.mp3 format
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C  REN c:\full\path\*.mp3 c:\full\path\*1.mp3";
cmd.Start();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: @loopedcode - Doesn't this approach have a couple of security issues? Don't you need to have full access rights to launch a process? And then a hacker could change the %PATH% variable to point to a malicious "cmd.exe"? Might be fast, but I think it's a little unsafe. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead:

```
Directory.GetFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath, "*.mp3")
    .Select(fn => new
    {
        OldFileName = fn,
        NewFileName = String.Format("{0}1.mp3", fn.Substring(fn.Length - 4))
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => File.Move(x.OldFileName, x.NewFileName));
```

Comment: I think loopedcode's code has better performance but your code also deserves a +1, nice written

Answer (score 0):

as friends discussed in the comments, you can either declare newFileName as a simple string (instead of array of strings) or use code below if you intend to use array:

```
newFileName[i] = mp3Files[i];
```

and since you are using for loop you'd better use string and not array of strings.